# Ошибка при создании исполняемого файла Python

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Приложение, написанное на Python я хочу собрать в исполняемый файл.
В коде используется куча разных библиотек (pandas,numpy,opencv,torch,scikit и т.д и т.п)
Использую pyinstaller. Сборка происходит в Ubuntu
Команда на сборку:

```
pyinstaller app.py -n myApp --paths="/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.9/"
```

Выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "torch/_utils_internal.py", line 55, in get_source_lines_and_file
sourcelines, file_lineno = inspect.getsourcelines(obj)
File "inspect.py", line 1006, in getsourcelines
File "inspect.py", line 835, in findsource
OSError: could not get source code

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 18, in <module>
File "/tmp/embedded.6b51yd_m.zip/shibokensupport/__feature__.py", line 142, in  _import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
File "context_menu_slots.py", line 3, in <module>
File "/tmp/embedded.6b51yd_m.zip/shibokensupport/__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
File "modals/cut_window.py", line 5, in <module>
File "/tmp/embedded.6b51yd_m.zip/shibokensupport/__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
File "commands.py", line 1, in <module>
File "/tmp/embedded.6b51yd_m.zip/shibokensupport/__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
File "hsi_torch/preprocessing/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
File "/tmp/embedded.6b51yd_m.zip/shibokensupport/__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
File "hsi_torch/preprocessing/cube_transform.py", line 3, in <module>
File "/tmp/embedded.6b51yd_m.zip/shibokensupport/__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
File "kornia/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
File "/tmp/embedded.6b51yd_m.zip/shibokensupport/__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
File "kornia/jit/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
File "torch/jit/_script.py", line 986, in script
  ast = get_jit_def(obj, obj.__name__)
File "torch/jit/frontend.py", line 240, in get_jit_def
  sourcelines, file_lineno, filename = get_source_lines_and_file(fn,   torch._C.ErrorReport.call_stack())
File "torch/_utils_internal.py", line 62, in get_source_lines_and_file
  raise OSError(msg) from e
OSError: Can't get source for <function rgb_to_grayscale at   0x7f75400940d0>.   TorchScript requires source access in order to   carry out compilation, make sure original   .py files are available.
[67302] Failed to execute script app
```

Как это исправить? Или может есть более удобные средства для сборки приложений?

Comment: Нагуглилось: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66646204/5909792 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/62175881/5909792 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/56325181/5909792

Comment: Вторая ссылка помогла. Благодарю